# Javascript function not assigning proper value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have following javascript function:

```
function editWebsite(IP)
{

 document.getElementById('ctl04_txtIP').value = IP;

}
```

`ctl04_txtIP` is textbox representing `IP adress` comming through parameter `IP` of `editWebsite` function.

Proble is that , when i see that textbox, value of IP variable is different and actual value shown in the textbox is different.

When I adds `alert('Any message')` in the function, it shows me value correctly, but as soon as I removes alert and makes my JavaScript function as above, value differs.

I am not able to understand how it is happening.

I am using visual studio 2008 (ASP.NET)

I have created one link Dynamically through c# code, on click of which this function gets called>>

```
"<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"javascript:editWebsite('" + Convert.ToString(dr["IP"]) + "')\">Edit</a>"
```

Comment: It smells like an asynchronicity problem. Can you give us more relevant code ? A fiddle would also help us help you.

Comment: @dystroy Code is as above only

Comment: No, your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @dystroy sir, in the same function if i adds alert box of any message then it shows me values correctly

Comment: @dystroy sir it also does not effects if i writes alert box after assigning of values

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting a delay before assigning the value?

```
function editWebsite(IP)
{
 setTimeout(function() {
 document.getElementById('ctl04_txtIP').value = IP;
 }, 100);
}
```

Comment: You're hiding a bug in a terrible way.

Comment: The **real** problem is that you're calling your function too early, during some asynchronous query. Both the alert and the setTimeout, when you're lucky, make the script wait for the return of the function. We need more code to solve the problem.